# Mockoon Docker compose : Error: Missing required flag

Tags: docker-compose, mocking, mockoon

I'm trying to run mockoon docker cli using docker compose for my mock api and i have the json exported to my directory,

```
version: "3"
services:
  mockoon:
    image: mockoon/cli:latest
    command: mockoon-cli start
    networks:
      demo:
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./mock.json
        target: /www
networks:
  demo:
```

when i run docker-compose up the container comes up for few seconds and shuts down with the following log

```
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›    -d, --data DATA  Path(s) or URL(s) to your Mockoon data file(s)
 ›   See more help with --help
```

Any additional settings that i should make or i have missed something in my config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the official documentation, you need to specify the `--data` directory inside the docker-compose `command` line.

So the compose file would like like this:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mockoon:
    image: mockoon/cli:latest
    command: mockoon-cli start  --data <directory> # this is where the change takes place
    networks:
      demo:
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./mock.json
        target: /www
networks:
  demo:
```

[mockoon cli](https://mockoon.com/cli/)

Comment: i use this
version: "3"
services:
  mockoon:
    image: mockoon/cli:latest
    container_name: mockoon
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    command: mockoon-cli start -d https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mockoon/mock-samples/main/samples/generate-mock-data.json

and this error appear
mockoon  |  ›   Error: Unexpected arguments: mockoon-cli, start
mockoon  |  ›   See more help with --help
mockoon exited with code 2

Answer (score 1):

The "data" after the --data flag is the alias to the file name, not the folder name. Hence, it should be:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chicargo-mockoon-mock:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mockoon/cli:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./your-file-name.json
        target: /data
    command: mockoon-cli start  --data data
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the similar problem and found that:

1. It's better to link environment as a data rather than swagger file for better experience with mockoon lib.
2. Do not include `mockoon-cli start` to the `command:` as it is already included in the ENTRYPOINT.
   This works for me:

```
version: "3"
 services:
   mockoon-mock:
     image: mockoon/cli
     command: ["--data", "data"]
     ports:
       - "8001:8001"
     volumes:
       - ./myFolder/myEnvironmentFile.json:/data
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/tree/main/packages/cli#using-the-generic-docker-image)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, and after extensive searching, I came across these results:

1. You need too provide a `.json` or `.yaml` file as an open API
   specification that has info about your API mock data. See this `json` example below:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": { "title": "Sample API", "version": "1.0.0" },
  "paths":
    {
      "/users":
        {
          "get":
            {
              "summary": "Retrieve all users",
              "operationId": "getUsers",
              "responses":
                {
                  "200":
                    {
                      "description": "Successful operation",
                      "schema":
                        { "type": "array", "items": { "type": "string" } }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
      "/users/{id}":
        {
          "get":
            {
              "summary": "Get a user by ID",
              "operationId": "getUserById",
              "parameters":
                [
                  {
                    "name": "id",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                  }
                ],
              "responses":
                {
                  "200":
                    {
                      "description": "Successful operation",
                      "schema":
                        {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties":
                            {
                              "id": { "type": "integer", "format": "int64" },
                              "name": { "type": "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. As you see in `compose.yaml` example below, you have to only set `--data` flag and no need for `mockoon-cli` or `start` command. Also when you are setting `volume` property you should address to `.json` or `.yaml` file and not only the directory.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mockoon:
    image: mockoon/cli:latest
    command: [ "--data", "/openapi/openapi.json" ]
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./openapi-specification.json:/openapi/openapi.json
```

This worked for me. I hope it's helpful for you as well.